# Getting all tr with a particular background-color using selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-table

I have a table with many rows. Some rows are having a prticular colour and I want to get an array of that tr elements using jquery. I used selectors but didnt work

```
$("#tbodySample").children("tr[background-color='rgb(79,79,79)']").length;

$("#tbodySample").children("tr[style='background-color:rgb(79,79,79)']").length;

$("#tbodySample").children("tr[style='{background-color:rgb(79,79,79)}']").length;

$("#tbodySample").children("tr[background-color='#4F4F4F']").length;

$("#tbodySample").children("tr[style='background-color:#4F4F4F']").length;

$("#tbodySample").children("tr[style='{background-color:#4F4F4F}']").length;
```

My html is

```
<table>
<tbody id="tbodySample">
<tr class="selectable" style="background-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);">contents</tr>
<tr class="selectable" style="background-color: rgb(52, 52, 52);">contents</tr>
<tr class="selectable" style="background-color: rgb(52, 52, 52);">contents</tr>
<tr class="selectable" style="background-color: rgb(52, 52, 52);">contents</tr>
<tr class="selectable" style="background-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);">contents</tr>
.
.
.
</tbody>
</table>
```

All the above statements returns 0.
Is there any reliable way to achieve this?

Comment: Assign colors using css classes, then find elements with a certain class. Makes life much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use filter to check the background color. I'm checking the `.css('color')` against both hexadecimal values and rgb values for cross-browser compatibility:

```
var count = $('#tbodySample').find('tr').filter(function(){
    var colors = ["#4F4F4F","rgb(79, 79, 79)"];
    return $.inArray($(this).css('background-color'), colors) !== -1;
}).length;
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gz7xw0vo/1/)

Note: You have invalid HTML, `<td>` elements must be immediate children or `<tr>` elements

Comment: there are 5 tds in each tr I havent given it here

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped.

Comment: What would be the probable reason that not worked.
Does the style attribute cant be selected with selectors??

Comment: It should can, however the string you provide in the attribute selector must be **exactly** the same (including white-space) as the value in the actual attribute, which isn't ideal since CSS allows white-space in many places and your attribute could be inconsistent. http://jsfiddle.net/gz7xw0vo/2/

Comment: ok. If so can you please tell me which is the correct syntax from the statements I provided in the question

Comment: The second one. The only reason it doesn't work is because of the lack of a space between `background-color:` and `rgb(79, 79, 79)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#tbodySample tr[style*='background-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);']").length
```